# UITextField InputView background color issue in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios6, ios7

I am using a custom keyboard for UITextField. So i am assigning the custom view to the TextField inputView property. The CustomView background color appears as blackcolor in iOS7, where it is clearColor lessthan iOS7. Code and screenshots(iOs6,iOS7) is below:

```
keypadContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, appFrame.size.width, appFrame.size.height - ((self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.bounds.size.height) - kp.bounds.size.height))];
    keypadContainer.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [keypadContainer addSubview:buttonsView]; //Here buttonsView is the view which conatins buttons for 0 to 9 digits.

    numberField.inputView = keypadContainer;
    numberField.inputView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

[image: iOS6 Screenshot]

[image: iOS7 Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `keyPadContainer.opaque = NO`

Comment: No luck, still same issue.

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984525/uitextviews-inputview-on-ios-7

Comment: But sometimes it is crashing at   [[backdropView layer] setOpacity:0];
when i present one viewcontroller and dismiss it.